# integer output returning NaN in javascript

Tags: html, javascript

I'm trying to write this extremely simple javascript app where the user can input two numbers and the sum of these two is automatically outputted to screen. I'm very new to javascript so I'm not sure where I went wrong.  The following code will print NaN for a second after I press the button.  Any idea as to how I handle this input better?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function myFunction()
{
    var x = parseInt(first_num);
    var y = parseInt(second_num);
    var z = x + y;
    var a = z.toString();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;

}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Enter two numbers to be added together.</p>
<form>
<input id="first_num" name="first_num" > first num<br>

<input id="second_num" name="second_num" > second num
<button onclick="myFunction()">calculate</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Uhm, where is `first_num` and `second_num` coming from ?

Comment: The reason it goes away in a flash is because you're submitting the form. You need to add `;return false;` to your `onclick` so it doesn't submit.

Comment: You're also missing `</form>`.

Comment: @adeneo: global variables created from the element IDs.

Comment: @cookiemonster - that would be so called "named elements", and it's generally not a good idea to rely on those, but true, in the window scope the elements would be available that way.

Comment: @adeneo: Yeah, I agree that it's not a great idea to use those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/esxW2/).

The reason of NaN is you trying to parseInt with not initialized variable. beside this input tag is not closed.

```
function myFunction() {    
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById('first_num').value) + parseInt(document.getElementById('second_num').value);    
}
```

and html:

```
<p>Enter two numbers to be added together.</p>
<input id="first_num" name="first_num" />first num
<br>
<input id="second_num" name="second_num" />second num
<button onclick="myFunction()">calculate</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: I see, I see that I needed to close my input tag but why would that cause my output to only be temporary?  Is it because I am continuing to poll for new input when my tag is not closed?

Answer (score 2):

```
var x = parseInt(first_num);
var y = parseInt(second_num);
```

Instead of `first_num` and `second_num`, you need to retrieve the value from the input boxes, like this

```
var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("first_num").value);
var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("second_num").value);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a selector to get the value of the two `input` elements:

```
var x = parseInt(document.getElementById('first_num').value);
var y = parseInt(document.getElementById('second_num').value);
...
```

And you have to close your `form` tag in your HTML use and use a `<input type="button">` instead of `<button>` so your form doesn't post unnecessarily.

```
<form>
    <input id="first_num" name="first_num" > first num <br />
    <input id="second_num" name="second_num" > second num <br />
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="calculate">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Enter two numbers to be added together.</p>

    <input id="first_num" name="first_num">first num<br />
    <input id="second_num" name="second_num">second num<br />

    <button onclick="myFunction()">calculate</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("first_num").value;
            var y = document.getElementById("second_num").value;

            var z = ((x && x != "") ? parseInt(x) : 0) + ((y && y != "") ? parseInt(y) : 0);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
<p>Enter two numbers to be added together.</p>
<form>
<input id="first_num" name="first_num" > first num<br>

<input id="second_num" name="second_num" > second num
<button  onclick="myFunction(parseInt(document.getElementById("first_num").value),parseInt(document. getElementById("second_num").value))">calculate</button>

<p id="demo"></p>


function myFunction(first_num,second_num)
{
    var x = parseInt(first_num);
    var y = parseInt(second_num);
    var z = x + y;
    var a = z.toString();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;

}
```

Comment: I personally don't mind a simple function call inline, but IMO, that's quite a bit of code to embed, especially when you're calling a function anyway.

Comment: you right, but what I want to do is to disconnect the function from the html element, I can do: onclick="myFunction("first_num","second_num")" and inside the function i will get the dom element.